# how to make @id fields editable in forge crud?

Tags: jboss, annotations, crud, jboss-forge

I want to generate a crud for an entity with an editable primary key but forge doesnt generate the @id field this is my entity note that the id field is an string it is not a an auto increment id field.

```
package com.samples.model;

// Generated 14/01/2013 11:23:23 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Pais generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "pais", schema = "public")
public class Pais implements java.io.Serializable
{

   /**
   * 
   */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -8369022633869576848L;
   private String paisId;
   private Date fechaRegistro;
   private String descripcion;
   private short estatus;
   private Set<Estado> estados = new HashSet<Estado>(0);

   public Pais()
   {
   }

   public Pais(String paisId, Date fechaRegistro, short estatus)
   {
      this.paisId = paisId;
      this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
      this.estatus = estatus;
   }

   public Pais(String paisId, Date fechaRegistro, String descripcion, short estatus, Set<Estado> estados)
   {
      this.paisId = paisId;
      this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
      this.descripcion = descripcion;
      this.estatus = estatus;
      this.estados = estados;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name = "pais_id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 5)
   public String getPaisId()
   {
      return this.paisId;
   }

   public void setPaisId(String paisId)
   {
      this.paisId = paisId;
   }

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @Column(name = "fecha_registro", nullable = false, length = 29)
   public Date getFechaRegistro()
   {
      return this.fechaRegistro;
   }

   public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro)
   {
      this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
   }

   @Column(name = "descripcion", length = 30)
   public String getDescripcion()
   {
      return this.descripcion;
   }

   public void setDescripcion(String descripcion)
   {
      this.descripcion = descripcion;
   }

   @Column(name = "estatus", nullable = false)
   public short getEstatus()
   {
      return this.estatus;
   }

   public void setEstatus(short estatus)
   {
      this.estatus = estatus;
   }

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pais")
   public Set<Estado> getEstados()
   {
      return this.estados;
   }

   public void setEstados(Set<Estado> estados)
   {
      this.estados = estados;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

JBoss Forge uses [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) for its UI generation. So to accomplish this you must modify Forge's metawidget.xml configuration file.

Forge actually has 3 Metawidget configuration files: metawidget-entity.xml for viewing/editing screens, metawidget-search.xml for search filters, and metawidget-qbe.xml for generating Java code.

For your purposes, you need to modify metawidget-entity.xml. Specifically you must find the JpaInspector entry...

```
<jpaInspector xmlns="java:org.metawidget.inspector.jpa" config="JpaInspectorConfig">
```

...and add a child node...

```
<hideIds><boolean>false</boolean></hideIds>
```

That bit should be straightforward. However actually getting your modified metawidget-entity.xml back into Forge is clumsy. At the moment the easiest way is probably to unzip and modify the forge-scaffold-faces.jar itself. Hopefully this will be made cleaner in a future Forge release.